# excanvas refusing to work in IE8 despite executing in load event

Tags: javascript, html, charts, internet-explorer-8, excanvas

```
if(/MSIE (\d+\.\d+); /.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  var foo = document.getElementById('herd-reports-report-table-div');
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  c.setAttribute("width",800);
  c.setAttribute("height",400);
  c.setAttribute("class","mapping");
  foo.appendChild(c);
  c = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(c);
} else {
  var c = document.getElementById('herd-report-chart-canvas');
}
var context = c.getContext('2d');
```

Let's say that I have this code executing in a function on load of a page, and I need a chart to be built. I have included excanvas, yet it won't work. IE8 throws an error at the last line. All I get is "null" error at the appendChild step. Or i get "Object is not supported by this property or method".

I'm at my wit's end. I need this canvas to work in IE8. Somehow.

Comment: Even though the library is included, I imagine that it doesn't include a shiv for `document.createElement('canvas');`. Try putting together the element in html instead of trying to create it with javascript and see if it works.

Comment: That's the kicker. I've tried just getting the predefined element in HTML by getting it by ID then getting the context. It does the same error no matter what. I still get that issue.

I've been mulling on it and I can't quite figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: Actually, let me add on. It works now, somehow. I think I had the conditional html include not working correctly. It's getting the context. Now to figure out how to fix something else that came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ultimately found the fix for why it (getContext) wasn't working. A few things

- My conditional comment for including excanvas wasn't correct.
- Outside that, mine didn't have the support for certain functions called on the canvas element by chart.js, so an update to the excanvas.js fixed that issue.
- I have everything working on load now, so that issue is also resolved.